# Zeroing margins on CSS a good practice?

Tags: html, css, margin

I just started to seriously study CSS and went through practicing my CSS skills. One particular issue I encountered was the first element on top would usually like to have a margin/padding on certain browsers.

So my question come down to, is it a good practice to do

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

on my CSS documents? I am reading mixed answers on this. Some say this makes compatibility across browsers awesome and some say it makes rendering slow (not a good idea on older systems).

EDIT:
I just researched into reset.css it seems very similar to what resetting * would do. I happen to come across normalize.css is that a better alternative to make it compatible across browsers?

EDIT2:
Thanks for all the suggestions. I now understand this issue a little bit more and it seems highly opinionated. It's just a question that will never go away due to the different ways browsers render their content.

Comment: You are reading mixed answers, because this is a matter of opinions, style, habits, and fashions. Consider asking a specific, well-defined question instead, e.g. how to remove top margin or padding for a particular page.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, most of the answers I'm getting is clearing up the cloud though. I am now able to ask more specific questions.

Comment: Take into account that reset.css might cause unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it all depends.
* reset, normalize, and reset.css all reset user agent styles. which one is best? depends on your document(s).
* is criticized because it resets everything, but if you don't have much in your document, it doesn't matter.

reset.css is the standard, but this can be overkill if you're not using all the elements it is resetting.

normalize is a lighter version of reset, same applies though.

i use normalize.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a reset.css in your html. [YUI 2: Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) has one you can download or link to.

It basically gives everything default values so there is less of a chance an user's browsers displays something different.